# format decimal by specifying a particular format

Tags: python

Is there a way to format a number in python like below:

```
DecimalFormat("00000.00000").format(getSettlmentPrice()).replace(".", "")
```

This is how it is done in java.

Comment: could you provide an example input and expected output

Comment: input is some float like .8333 or 1.55 and the output should be like 00000.83330 or 00001.55000.                                                                    It should be always 10 digits with 5 before decimal and 5 after.

Answer (score 0):

```
print "%11.5f" % settlementPrice
```

The format is for total width (including the decimal point), then the number of decimal places to keep.  See [format](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)